# How to stop chromebooks sshd? (pixelbook)

Tags: linux, chromebook

I can run the daemon just fine with `/usr/sbin/sshd -p 1337`

Then I can connect just fine, alternatively I can enable developer mode to start it.

But I dont know how to stop it... the command im familiar with `/usr/sbin/sshd stop` does not work. and results in the error

> Extra argument stop.

I tried using `sudo kill -9` but it just restarts.

Comment: Depending on how the services are started,  likely either `sudo service sshd stop` or `sudo systemctl stop sshd`  (note the servicename/operation reversal)

Comment: I just checked, `/sbin/init` ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18210/49853)). `/bin/systemctl` does not exist (no systemd), still appears to be upstart without `service` alias here on ChromeOS 63. I poked around a bit found this file https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/overlays/chromiumos-overlay/+/master/chromeos-base/chromeos-sshd-init/files/openssh-server.conf.README but for now I'm at my wits end and time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, but I already posted an answer, I just wasn't able to post it as an answer at the time. Also @xenoid, that solution does not work lol, who upvoted >_<?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** Use kill sig 15 on the process.

```
sudo kill -15 $(sudo ps -A |grep "\ssshd$" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
```

**Explanation:** It seams that pixelbook uses upstart with no service command. Also the sshd daemon needs to close with the *TERMINATE/15* signal, not *KILL/9*. I believe because it's a zombie process, eitherway I should have tried that first.

**Command explanation:** (If you know the PID you can just use `sudo kill -15 $PID`)

- `sudo`: run as elevated user
- `kill`: send a kill signal to kernal
- `-`: next arg is an option
- `15`: option for terminate signal
- `$()`: substitute expression (runs whats inside)
- `ps`: processes
- `A`: option for all
- `|`: send output to next command
- `grep`: gnu regexp
- `"\ssshd$"`: 1 space followed by string "sshd" followed by end of line
- `cut -d ' ' -f 1`: cut the first word after 1 space.

Comment: `pkill` would be a lot simpler, `pkill sshd` could be enough.

Comment: Doesnt work for me @xenoid, thanks though. both `pkill sshd` and `pkill -15 sshd` fail whereas `kill 15` still works for me.